# Powershell Active Directory how does the like filter work?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hello I simply don't understand how the like  works in powershell.

This line gives 1 record:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {DistinguishedName -eq "CN=Development,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=it"}
```

but this one:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {DistinguishedName -like "*Development*"}
```

doesn't return anything. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinguished Names cannot be wild-card matched with LDAP, which is what the `-Filter` will get translated to internally.

That's why you don't see any results

You could retrieve all OU's that contain "Development" in the name and search through them all:

```
$ADGroups = @()
$DevOUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {name -like "*ex*"}| Select-Object DistinguishedName

foreach($ou in $DevOUs)
{
    $DN = $ou.DistinguishedName
    foreach($Group in (Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $DN))
    {
        # Prevent duplicates
        if($ADGroups -notcontains $Group)
        { $ADGroups += $Group }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I could filter through the Distinguished Names values?